# TIPTAP editor, uploading info to database with nextjs

Tags: database, next.js, tiptap

I have installed the rich text editor TIPTAP. I am trying to update the data to the database but it doesn't upload any info. I am changing the following textarea(which works) to TIPTAP richtext.
               `<textarea className="form form-control" value={formState.description} onChange={handleInputChange} id="description" cols="30" rows="10" name="description" placeholder={!language ? 'description' : 'description'} style={{ marginBottom: '5vh' }} ></textarea>`

I have done it like this:
`<TipTap
value={formState.description}
onChange={handleInputChange}
id="description"
name="description"
placeholder={!language ? 'description' : 'description'}
setValue={setFormState.description}
/> ``

The TIPTAP component looks like this:
`const TipTap = ({ setValue}) => { const editor = useEditor({ extensions: [StarterKit, Underline, ListItem, TextStyle], content:`  `,

```
       onUpdate: ({ editor }) => {
      const json = editor.getJSON();
        setValue(json);
        },
        });

       return (
        <div className="text-editor">
       <MenuBar editor={editor} />
       <EditorContent editor={editor} name={name} value={value} />
      </div>
      );
      };
     export default TipTap;`
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try getHTML function?

```js
onUpdate() {
      setContentEditor(editor?.getHTML() || '');
    },
```

Comment: Thanks Delacyr, sorry, just say your response now but that is how I solved it